# Folding over HList?

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given:

```
import shapeless._
case class F(x: Option[Int], y: Option[Int])
```

I'd like help to write a function, `f`:

`def f(Option[Int] :: Option[Int] :: HNil): String`

such that each `Option[Int]` is replace with the `Some` number or `empty`; and `""` for `HNil`.

Example:

```
val res7 = Generic[F].to( F( Some(42), None) )
//res7: shapeless.::[Option[Int],shapeless.::
         [Option[Int],shapeless.HNil]] = Some(42) :: None :: HNil

f(res7) === "42empty"
```

How can `f` be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Poly`:

```
 object OptFolder extends Poly2{
   def conv(x: Option[Int]) = x.map(_.toString).getOrElse("empty")

   implicit val ff = at{ (y: String, z: Option[Int]) => y + conv(z) }
 }

 val lala: String = myHlist.foldLeft("")(OptFolder) //:String not required
```

So a `Generic` to transform to the `HList` and then a `foldLeft` with a well defined `Poly`.

Comment: Thanks, @wheaties. What's the meaning of `conv`, i.e. the function's name?